# MySQL: latest comments on each post

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Having the classic "posts table, and comments table with foreign key to posts table" scenario, what's the most efficient way to get the IDs of the last 20 posts ordered by the time of their last comment, and the actual comment itself?

Here is a query that works but can probably be done much more efficiently:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY time DESC
) AS foo GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20
```

A nested query with an `ORDER BY` is necessary to make sure that the latest comment gets selected into the `post_id` group.

Comment: For what database?  There's no consistent syntax for limiting results.

Comment: MySQL, clarified. Didn't think that SQL differed so much across database systems.

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182436/retrieveing-the-most-recent-records-within-a-query is practically the same question... "greatest-n-per-group" was the search term I was missing.

Comment: Yes, follow that tag for many other similar questions.

Comment: I don't quite understand. How does the ORDER BY time work when there's a GROUP BY post_id in the query?

Comment: The ORDER BY in the outer query sorts the rows after they've been grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: practically the same question as [Retrieveing the most recent records within a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182436/retrieveing-the-most-recent-records-within-a-query).

See the [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag for more similar questions.