# How can I include primary key when using SELECT MAX() and GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Given the following table:

```
TrackID  IMEI             LastPacketTime
45       862950022901642  2015-09-23 18:25:16.000
62       862950022901642  2015-09-24 06:50:16.000
99       862950022901642  2015-09-25 22:27:49.000
```

..how can I return the TrackID when I want to select the most recent row for every IMEI?    If I group by IMEI, I lose the ability to include the TrackID.

My current SQL is as follows (but doesn't include the TrackID which I need):

```
SELECT IMEI, MAX(LastPacketTime) AS LastPacketTime
FROM dbo.Tracks  
GROUP BY IMEI
```

Comment: Your `lastdate` for last 2 rows is same. Which track Id do you want to return in that case? both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the most recent records within a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182436/retrieving-the-most-recent-records-within-a-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)  for this:

```
SELECT TrackID,  IMEI, LastDate
FROM (
  SELECT TrackID,  IMEI, LastDate, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IMEI 
                            ORDER BY LastPacketTime DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.Tracks) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

If you have multiple records sharing the same maximum `LastPacketTime` value and you want the `TrackID` values of all these records returned, then use [**`RANK`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) in place of `ROW_NUMBER`.

**Edit:** In case of ties you can extend the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER` so as to selectively pick either the smaller `TrackID`:

```
ORDER BY LastPacketTime DESC, TrackID
```

or the bigger one:

```
ORDER BY LastPacketTime DESC, TrackID DESC
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this (it was scored higher) but it works perfectly for me (the OP) - many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic query but in case of same time appearing more than once, it would give maximum `trackid`.

```
select max(t1.trackid) as trackid,
    t1.imei,max(t1.lastdate)
from 
tracks t1 
    inner join 
tracks t2
    on t1.imei=t2.imei
where t1.lastdate > t2.lastdate
group by t1.imei,t1.lastdate
```